# ASP.NET - Rollback Database transaction when browser closing is detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a question and I will be grateful if you could share ideas.

I have a ASPX web page with a textbox and a button. The textbox contains an integer. When the button is clicked, it will be transferred to another page wherein a certain integer field in a database, subtracted with the value on the textbox is displayed. The value in the database also is reflected with the calculation.

However, when the browser is closed, I want to re-add the value to database, like a rollback. Will it be possible to do that?

Comment: You'll need to do it in JavaScript (have it run inside the browser and make API calls), and you'll have to deal with the user leaving the site over a link or via the back button as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3888938/9363973)

Comment: What if the browser crashes or there is a network error. There will be no rolback. I would not depend on a mechanic like this. Better rethink your design.